# C++ Outputting strings from a .txt file in to a dynamic array outside of a member methods local scope

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, stream, scope

To start with, is what I'm asking possible?

I currently have a program with one member method (Read) that reads in strings from a .txt file locally in one member method and just outputs the same data to the console. Now as it stands I can't do anything with the contents of the array, however I need the data to use in a Write method and wherever else in my code. I have used a dynamic C style array because that is what is required of me, no vector's etc are permitted. A solution or any general direction would be fantastic!

My structure is comprised of one Main.cpp, an ArrayStorage.cpp class definition and an ArrayStorage.h header file.

My code is below:

**ArrayStorage.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayStorage.h"
using namespace std;


void ArrayStorage::read(ifstream &fin1)
{
    int index = 0;
    int arrayLength = 0;
    string firstWord;

    if(fin1.is_open())
        {
            fin1 >> firstWord;
            fin1 >> arrayLength;

            string* arrayOfWords;
            arrayOfWords = new string[arrayLength];

            while(!fin1.eof())
            {
                fin1 >> arrayOfWords[index];
                cout << arrayOfWords[index];
                cout << "\n";
                index++;
            }

            delete [] arrayOfWords;

            fin1.close();
        }
}

void ArrayStorage::write(ofstream &out1)
{
    //fout.close();
}
```

**ArrayStorage.h**

```
#include <fstream> // Reading/Writing from file requires this standard library.
#include <iostream> // Needed for cin and cout
#include <ostream> // Needed for outputting to output file
#include <string> // Needed for string values
using namespace std;

#pragma once

class ArrayStorage
{
private:



public:

    void read(ifstream &fin1); //reads data from a file
    void write(ofstream &out1); //output data to an output stream(ostream)
    bool exists(); //return true or false depending whether or not a given word exists
    void stdExists(); //^^ use either std::count() or std::find() inside here


};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ArrayStorage.h"
#include "LinkedListStorage.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

string find = "pixel";

ifstream fin1("ACW2_data.txt");
ofstream out1("1-In-SortedRead.txt");

if(!fin1.is_open()) 
{
    cout << "FAIL" << endl;
    return 1;
}

ArrayStorage arrayStorage1;

// read in values into data structure
arrayStorage1.read(fin1);

// output values in data structure to file
arrayStorage1.write(out1);

fin1.close();
out1.close();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: add arrayOfWords as a data member of ArrayStorage and use it in any methods of your class

Comment: As in move "string* arrayOfWords;" under "private: " in my header file?

Comment: yes, arrayOfWords will become a data member of your class.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked once I removed the "delete [] arrayOfWords;" from my class.cpp

Which leads me to my question, won't there be a memory leak somewhere? Where should I free up my allocated memory space now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AnatolyS said, you should make arrayOfWords a private member variable of your class.

Then to make sure there are no memory leaks or access violation errors, I'd recommend the following:

1. Initialize it to NULL in the constructor

   ```
   void ArrayStorage::ArrayStorage()
       : arrayOfWords(NULL)
   {}
   ```
2. Delete it in the destructor if it is not NULL

   ```
   void ArrayStorage::~ArrayStorage()
   {
       if (arrayOfWords)
           delete []arrayOfWords;
   }
   ```
3. When reading a new file, delete the old array in case the same class is being used to read multiple files (assuming that's the behavior you want).

   ```
   if (arrayOfWords)
       delete []arrayOfWords;
   arrayOfWords = new string[arrayLength];
   ```
4. In your "Write" function (or any other function that accesses the array), check that it's not NULL before trying to use it.

Another thing you could do is check that the "new" operator doesn't return a NULL pointer (which could happen if you're out of memory).

This example illustrates why classes like vector are so useful, since they handle a lot of these allocation/deallocation details for you.

Comment: That's great man! Thanks a lot. And i'd use vectors if i could, trust me. Dynamic C Style Array's are a pain in the ass!